# python data frames - splitting string column into two columns

Tags: python, pandas, split

I'm playing with Whatsapp's history chat.
I want to split the message column into two columns - time and message.

[image]

In order to split the two with the delimiter " - " I tried:

```
history['message'] = pd.DataFrame([line.split(" - ",1) for line in history['message']])
```

But history['message'] becomes the time only.

I don't understand why, because the line.split(" - ", 1) supposes to give a list of 2 elements at most.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` for return `DataFrame`:

```
history = pd.DataFrame({'message':['a - b','c - d - r']})

history[['a','b']] = history['message'].str.split(' - ', n=1, expand=True)
print (history)
     message  a      b
0      a - b  a      b
1  c - d - r  c  d - r
```

If no `NaNs` use:

```
history[['a','b']] = pd.DataFrame([line.split(" - ", 1) for line in history['message']])
```

For me return error:

```
history['a'] = pd.DataFrame([line.split(" - ", 1) for line in history['message']])
print (history)
```

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

So if for you it working, try check separator, because it seems there is no `split`:

Sample:

```
history['a'] = history['message'].str.split('^', n=1, expand=True)
print (history)
     message          a
0      a - b      a - b
1  c - d - r  c - d - r
```